# Accessing SVN repository (located in another ubuntu machine) from eclipse

Tags: svn, ubuntu, subclipse

how do i access svn repo located in another system(both the system are in same LAN) from eclipse using subclipse.

I am getting repo not found,when trying to connect to  repo in eclipse.

please can anybody tell how do i access the repo from one machine to another.

Comment: can you do it from command line? maybe you are giving it wrong options?

Comment: Also, check your firewall settings - both on the client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what the SVN URL looks like.  If it starts with

```
http://
https://
svn://
```

Then you just need to start at "Create project from SVN repository"... [Here are some instructions to provide guidance.](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/eclipse-svn-project-checkout.html)

If it looks like something else, then you need to set up the SVN server to serve SVN across a computer network.